# Excel 2010 VBA Help Copying Ranges of Columns

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

My code works almost as desired. It checks all sheets for a certain value in Column "F" and then copies its associated row to the active sheet. I can make the code copy the entire row, singular columns "A", or sequential ranges "A:C". I cannot seem to make it copy specific columns like "A" "C" & "F" which is what I need it to do.

```
Public Sub List()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

ActiveSheet.Rows("3:" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).Clear
Selection.Clear

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then

        For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            If ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Pending" Then

                ws.Cells(i, "A").Columns("A:D").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            End If

        Next

    End If

Next
```

Comment: you can use sth like this: `Range("A:A,C:C,F:F").Copy Destination:=Range("H1")`

Comment: I had tried this previously and depending on which variation I do I get different errors 'ws.Cells(i, "A").Range("A:A,C:C,E:E").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)' gives me a runtime error 1004 an application or object define error &  'ws.Cells(i, "A").Columns("A:A,C:C,E:E").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)' gives me a run time error 13 Type Mismatch

Comment: When you use `Range("A:A,C:C,E:E")` you tries to paste values in lastrow of column `A` (say `A10`). But it coudn't be done, because excel tries to paste _entire_ columns and there is no place for pasting it (9 lines are missing). If you will change `Destination` to `Destination:=Range("A1")` it will work. So, the best idea is to refactor your code..

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses. Maybe I am going about this wrong for what I want it to do. I want it to check all sheets for value "Pending" in column "F" if they are found in say row10 I want A10,C10,& E10 copied to the active sheet. I just tried what you suggested and got the same runtime 1004 error. 'ws.Cells(i, "A").Range("A:A,C:C,E:E").Copy Destination:=Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)'

Comment: try this one: `ws.Range("A" & i & ", C" & i & ", E" & i).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` . (p.s. if it helps, say please and I'll post it like an answer)

Comment: That did the trick!! I owe you if you're feeling extra generous would you want to explain it?? Thanks either way!!

Comment: So, for `i=20` expression `ws.Range("A" & i & ", C" & i & ", E" & i).Copy` is equal to `ws.Range("A20, C20, E20").Copy`. It copies exact cells you want:)

Comment: Why the different quotations and ampersands it doesn't follow a pattern could you explain the arguments?

Comment: When you going to concatenate string and somethnig from another value, you are using `&` as follows: `"A" & i`. In this statement VBA gets value of `i` (say `20`), casts it to the `String` type and add to the string `"A"`. So we will get `"A20"`. With other  ampersands  the same thing - they concatenate values in string: `"A" & i` returns `"A20"`, then `"A20" & ", C"` returns `"A20, C"`, then `"A20, C" & i` returns `"A20, C20"`, finally `"A20, C20" & ", E" & i` returns `"A20, C20, E20"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As following from comments to Question, correct answer is to use following line:

```
ws.Range("A" & i & ", C" & i & ", E" & i).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

instead

```
ws.Cells(i, "A").Columns("A:D").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```